# X in base and exponent

Tags: linear-algebra

$$-39,125\cdot x\cdot1.3^x + 5\cdot1.3^x - 5 - 100 \cdot x = 0$$

How to find $x$ if it is in base and in exponent? Or how to make this equation more easier?

Comment: Do you mean "*" for multiplication ? You may use \times or \cdot

Comment: Yes. Sorry for it

Answer (score 1):

Take the equation: 
$-39125\!\cdot\!x\cdot  1.3^x + 5\!\cdot\!1.3^x - 5 - 100\!\cdot\!x = 0$

Associate like terms:
$1.3^x (5-39125 x) = 5+100x$

Rearrange and cancel common factors:
$1.3^x = \frac{1+20x}{1-7825 x}$

Take the log and rearrange:
$x = \dfrac{ \ln(\frac{1+20x}{1-7825 x}) }{\ln 1.3}$

This can be examined by iteration.

Conclude:
$x=0$